# mmenu.js : How to search synonyms?

Tags: jquery-plugins, mmenu

I am using the [mmenu.js](https://mmenujs.com) jQuery plugin. It's search function can only search the textnode within each menu item's  tag. So for example, I have a menu item like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Film</a></li>
```

The search function can only find it with the search keyword 'film'. I need it to find this menu item also with the search keyword 'movie'. So maybe something like:

```
<li><a href="#" synonym="movie">Film</a></li>
```

I tried:

```
<li><a href="#">Film <span class="hide">movie</span></a></li>
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a span with display:none; and your keywords inside as per your second method above. A recent update (March 2022) addressed this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).